# d3 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of null

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Here is my code:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg");
console.log(svg.attr);
svg.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right);
svg.attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom);
svg.append("g");
svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
```

The console.log(svg) outputs:

```
function (t,e){if(arguments.length<2){if("string"==typeof t){var n=this.node();return t=ja.ns.qualify(t),t.local?n.getAttributeNS(t.space,t.local):n.getAttribute(t)}for(e in t)this.each(xe(e,t[e]));return this}return this.each(xe(t,e))}
```

However when I try to call svg.attr method right after that, I get this in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'attr' of null
```

Can anybody explain this? Clearly svg is not null as I log it in console before trying to use it...

[image]

Comment: What's the code you're calling when you get this error?

Comment: Can you see some stack output, to see exactly when this rogue .attr() is called? It could be called from somewhere within the svg.attr(...) function itself.